# Error invoking remote method 'docker-start-container': Error: (HTTP code 400) unexpected

Tags: docker

Error invoking remote method 'docker-start-container': Error: (HTTP code 400) unexpected - failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "./entrypoint.sh": stat ./entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory: unknown

Comment: same happened to me today, using docker desktop, version 4.12.0